# what real world language does this look like?

Tags: writing-systems

This isn't really about a conlang, it's an alternative orthography but I didn't know where else to ask it. 
I found an alternative orthography for english called 'EBEO'(Even Better English Orthography) at https://alternatescriptbureau.wordpress.com/2018/02/09/ebeo-a-phonetic-orthography-for-english/. it uses the letters á, à, ā, ȧ, é, è, ē, í, ó, ò, ō. ú, ū, ù, đ, ŋ, ś, ŧ, ŵ & ź in addition to the standard english letters. What language does that look like (ŵat láŋúaj das đát luk lāk?)

Here's the Universal Declaration of Human Rights & the days of the week in EBEO:

Ól hùmen bíŋs ar born frí ánd ikūl in dignití ánd rāts. Đē ar éndàd wiŧ rízen ánd konśens ánd śud ákt tòerds wan enađer in e spirit of brađerhud. (Artikel 1 of đe Ùniversal Déklárēśen of Hùmen Rāts)

dēz av đ wík

- mandē
- túzdē
- winzdē
- ŧerzdē
- frādē
- sáterdē
- sandē

dē is day

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What real world language does this look like? It reminds me of either Polish or Turkish because of all accented letters, but neither of them use 'ŧ'.

Comment: I don't really think this is on-topic here.

Comment: *shrug* Looks like a poor attempt to write English.  Right from the title we can tell it's a losing proposition devised by yet another windmilltilting "reformer". After all, if it's supposed to be "fenetik", whose phonology is going to be used as the basis of what constitutes phonetic? Too much silliness in that article!

Comment: @curiousdannii - I concur that "what does it look like" kinds of questions are off topic (too subjective); but I think the orthography itself, silly as it is, ought probably to be on topic. Our [List of Licit and Banned Topics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is pretty sparse, after all!

Comment: @jastako - I could be wrong, but I don't think the argument is against the topic per se so much as the wording & nature of your query. Take a look at the [tour] and especially the [help], Pay especial attention to [what not to ask](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Right, we have other questions about constructed orthographies for natlangs. What other natlangs this looks like is quite subjective though, and isn't a useful question.

Comment: I said it wasn't really about a conlang, but I didn't know where else to post it. @elemtilas It is an attempt to write English. I don't think all of them are a horrible idea. I think English is in the minority in terms of languages that use 2 letters for sounds like 'ch'. 'C' being used for 'ʧ' also means c, s, & k all have one sound, & Ś (∫) & Ź(ʒ) are also used in Polish & Montenegrin as palatalized forms of S & Z. The vowel choices are what doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: The point of my question was if there is a natlang that actually uses all of those letters because there are quite a few languages whose alphabets are just heavily accented versions of the Latin alphabet. If I knew a more appropriate place to ask it I would've asked it there.

Comment: @jastako - I'm sorry, but I think perhaps we're miscommunicating with you, and for that, I at least apologise. To clarify, the ***content*** of your query is perfectly fine. Invented writing systems are perfectly on topic here.  What is off topic here, and indeed everywhere on stack exchange, is the ***subjective nature*** of the query. If you just want general chat, I'd suggest reddit; but the bar is set a little higher here. An easy fix, I think, would be a simple change of approach. In stead of asking what it reminds us of, ask about the aesthetic principles involved, perhaps (cont)

Comment: (cont) ...with a focus on influences from other languages' aesthetic forms. This way, you get your underlying question answered and we get a better quality, not so chatty, not so subjective question to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like a sample of an English based creole language written down by an amateur linguist or a missionary in a private orthography. It looks like a first attempt on a writing system for a previously unwritten language, it does not look really ripe: Too many diacritics on the vowels, and some confusable diacritics, too, e.g., **á, à, ā, ȧ**, what do they become in handwriting?

EDIT: Also important: What happens when all diacritics are left out, is this writing system still readable and understandable, or does it fail under such circumstances?